# XAML вертикальный отступ между двумя Label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Если вставить подряд два label, между ними образуется некое пространство, но мне нужно убрать это пространство так, чтобы тексты первого и второго практически соприкасались друг с другом. Уже всё перепробовал: и задавал им HeightRequest, и клал каждый Label в свой отдельный StackLayout и задавал HeightRequest StackLayout'у, везде проставлял Margin="0", Padding="0", VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand", Spacing="0", но задачу не удалось решить.

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding PickEvent, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0">
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="10" Padding="0" Margin="0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Date}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource Grey}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="10" Padding="0" Margin="0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource h1}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Подскажите как решить задачу, если это вообще возможно?

Comment: что за StackLayout? Из сторонней библиотеки? В стандартных контейнерах такого нету. А вы не пробовали поставить эти Label  в один контейнер? Типа вашего StackLayout но вместе?
`

Comment: @Ackbar StackLayout это контейнер Xamarin. Да, пробовал, изначально так и было, этот код уже последняя изменённая версия, которая тоже не работает как ожидается.

Comment: @Alias автор выше и написал что ему не помогла установка Spacing в ноль

Comment: О, ребят, Spacing="0" и правда помогло. В коде из моего примера есть StackLayout, в него вложены еще два StackLayout и в каждом из них по лэйблу. Так вот этим вложенным StackLayout я прописал Spacing="0", а родительскому - нет, но так как не совсем понимал что такое Spacing и не стал прописывать. Гуглил по "xaml label height", поэтому и не нашел ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: **Spacing="0"** для StackLayout.
Мою задачу решает следующий код:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0" Spacing="0">
 <Label Text="{Binding Date}" Margin="10,0,10,0" HeightRequest="12" Style="{StaticResource Grey}" />
 <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,0,10,0" HeightRequest="14" Style="{StaticResource h1}" />
</StackLayout>
```